# the form is always valid in symfony2

Tags: php, validation, symfony, symfony-forms

I have a form with this validation:

```
# ITW/UserBundle/Resources/config/validation.yml

ITW\UserBundle\Entity\User:
    properties:
        name:
            - NotBlank: ~
            - Length: { min: 800 }
```

And i'm checking the form like this:

```
// ITW/UserBundle/Controller/UserController.php

    $entity = new User();
    $form = $this->createForm(new UserType(), $entity);

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        echo "valid!";
    }
```

and in `config.yml` the validation is:

```
validation:      { enabled: true }
```

But while I'm submitting the form with empty `name` field , the `$form->isValid()` is always returning `True` !!!

I can't figure out what is wrong!
I'm sure that `validation.yml` is loading properly (as when I use invalid field name symfony gives exception)

Where is the problem?

---

Symfony version is `2.5.6` & I also tried with `2.5.5`
I also tried with `getters` constraint target for field `name` and got the same result.

---

My `UserType` is:

```
namespace ITW\UserBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use ITW\UserBundle\Entity\User;

class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    public function __construct(){}

    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('name','text',array('required'  => true,'label'=>'name'))
        ->add('family','text',array('required'  => true,'label'=>'family'))
        ->add('tels','collection', array('required'  => false,'prototype'=>true,'type'=> 'text','allow_add'=>true,'delete_empty'=>true,'label'=>'Tel'))
        ->add('username','text',array('required'  => true,'label'=>'username'))
        ->add('password','password',array('required'  => true,'label'=>'password'));

    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'ITW\UserBundle\Entity\User'
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'itw_userbundle_user';
    }
}
```

Comment: Accorded to [Symfony2 doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/validation.html#configuration), Do you have this ? `validation: { enable_annotations: true }` in framework section of your `app/config/config.yml` ?

Comment: @AlexandreL. No as I'm not using `annotations` i'm using `validation.yml` ; anyway I have also tested with `annotations` & it fails too ; please check 3 last lines of my question

Comment: @Chausser: version 2.5.6

Comment: Have you tried with Validator (`$validator = $this->get('validator');`) ?

Comment: @AlexandreL. yes and it gives empty error too

Comment: @Chausser: still it is valid!!

Comment: What does your UserType look like?

Comment: @Chausser, I added `UserType` class to the question.

Comment: how are you submitting the form without a name if the name field is required?

Comment: I added `{'attr': {'novalidate': 'novalidate'}}` to the form but I also tried to set `required` to false and got same result

Comment: very strange, im using 2.5.6 and duplicated your setup and my validation works fine. Do you have any services that hook the validator? Or could otherwise interfere with validation?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63892/discussion-between-chausser-and-4r1y4n).

Answer (score 0):

Just for clarification, configuration `validation` is [enabled by default](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/DependencyInjection/FrameworkExtension.php#L90) if you haven't removed section `form` from your `config.yml` file.

```
framework:
    form: ~
```

Comment: Problem solved with the help of @Chausser ; the chat link is at the end of comments; Changing whitespace control of error theme solved it!!! (why?!)